# Adjusting for probabilities of different updates in Metropolis Hastings

Tags: bayesian, simulation, metropolis-hastings

I have a problem with specifying the update probability in MH.

Assume we have the following setup in Metropolis-Hastings. We want to target a (2N-1)-dimensional posterior of parameters $(\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_N, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_N)$; we call it $\pi(\alpha, \beta)$. Moreover, we would like to update the parameters in pairs, i.e. $(\alpha_k, \beta_k)$ will be updated jointly for $k \geq 2$.

My current setup is as follows.

1. We pick an index $k \in \{1, \ldots, N\}$ uniformly at random.
2. There are two possible updates:

a)  If $k = 1$ (which happens with probability $\frac{1}{N}$), we set $\alpha_p = \alpha$, $\beta_p = \beta$ and then $\beta_{p1} = \beta_1 + unif(-\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1)$ - a random walk update.

b) If $k \neq 1$ (which happens with probability $\frac{N-1}{N}$), we set $\alpha_p = \alpha$, $\beta_p = \beta$, and $\alpha_{pk} = \alpha_k + unif(-\epsilon_2, \epsilon_2)$, $\beta_{pk} = \beta_k + unif(-\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1)$; again a random walk proposal for both parameters.

3. We accept the proposal with the following probability: $acc(\alpha_p, \beta_p \vert \alpha, \beta) =  \min\left(1, \frac{\pi(\alpha_p, \beta_p)}{\pi(\alpha, \beta)}\right)$

Should I somehow adjust for the different probabilities of the updates? If yes, how would I do this?

Comment: If $k=1$ do you also update $\alpha_1$? In this case it is correct. Else $\alpha_1$ never gets updated, incorrectly.

Comment: When $k  = 1$, I do not update $\alpha_1$; it is a fixed parameter, so it never gets updated (the alphas are angles in a polar coordinate system, so I need to fix one to break the symmetry). Thank you for help, professor!

Comment: Then if $\alpha_1$ is not an unknown parameter, there is no density on it and it should vanish from the expressions. But this remains a correct MH algorithm.